# How can I send data to the serial port from a Linux shell?

Tags: linux, serial-port, disk-operating-system

I need to find the linux way of running the following DOS commands:

```
MODE COM1: 9600,N,8,1,P
COPY FIRMWARE.COD COM1
```

Is this possible? I know COM1 in Linux is `/dev/ttyS0` but that's about it.
How do you set the mode on it and perform the copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set tty device settings:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600 -parity cs8 -cstopb
```

Send data:

```
cat firmware.cod > /dev/ttyS0
```